# Showing f has a pole

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f \colon \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic. Assume that image of the punctured open unit disk $B(0,1)\setminus \{0\}$ is exactly exterior of the closed unit disk. Show that $0$ is a pole for $f$.

My idea: Assume not. Then $f$ is an entire function. By continuity at $0$ and assumption on image of the  punctured open unit disc, $|f(0)|\ge 1$. More precisely, $|f(0)|> 1$, since otherwise, $\frac{1}{|f|}$ attains local maximum at interior point of $B(0,1)$, which contradicts maximum modulus principle. Any idea how to prove this actually?

Comment: How can a function whose domain is not $\Bbb C$ be entire?

Comment: I say that if 0 is not a pole, then I can extend $f$ in 0. This extension, say $\tilde{f}$, is entire...

Comment: You made no reference to extending in your post. Anyway, what about $f(z)=\exp\left(\frac1z\right)$? In this case, $0$ is not a pole. How do you extend $f$ to an entire function?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The assumption on $f$ with $B(0,1) \setminus \{0\}$ means that the singularity cannot be essential. Since it's not a pole either, the singularity is removable, and so $f$ is (extendable to an) entire (function).

Comment: your idea seems good maybe add some theorems to be sure you can do it?

Comment: I thought that abusive writing of $f(0)$ is self explanatory...

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace I have a feeling that I should invoke Liouville's theorem. But not sure how...

Comment: I think José was moreso asking you to justify the fact that the singularity was not essential, though of course I can't speak for him.

Comment: Anyway, hint: what can you say about, for example, the image of the closed unit disk?

Answer (score 1):

The singularity at $0$ is not essential by assumption, because the image of $B(0,1) \setminus \{0\}$ is not dense in $\mathbb{C}$.
Assume by contradiction that the singularity is not a pole.

Then, the singularity must be removable, hence $f$ is (extendable to an) entire (function). Therefore $f$ is continuous on $\overline{B}(0,1)$ compact, hence $f$ is bounded on the closed unit disk, yet that contradicts the assumption that the image of $B(0,1) \setminus \{0\}$, contained in the image of the closed unit disk, is $\mathbb{C} \setminus \overline{B}(0,1)$ thus unbounded.

We can conclude that the singularity at $0$ is indeed a pole.